# IllegalArgumentException thrown by requestLocationUpdate()

Tags: android, geolocation, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, illegalargumentexception

We recently tested our application against android API level 14 and 15. We started development targeting minimal SKD Version 8 and excluding tablets (3.x).
With 2.x everything works well but when running the app on a 4.x droid it crashes at the point we're obtaining user's location.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network  
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2263)  
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:123)  
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)  
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)  
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)  
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network  
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1331)  
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)  
at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:646)  
at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:582)   
at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:446)  
at package.name.LocationGetter.onCreate(LocationGetter.java:63)  
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2253)  
...
```

Source:

```
public void onCreate() {
  locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 300000, 500, locationListener);
  super.onCreate();
 }
```

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) an IAE is thrown `if provider or listener is null`.
However I logged the provider and listener. (the latter via toString() ) and they're not null.

Coming from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271041/problem-requesting-location-updates-by-network) I found an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19857). However I was wondering how people that are more confident with ice cream sandwich request user's coordinates.
[The tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) I know of uses the same approach described above.

Comment: I think you should make the `super()` the first call of your `onCreate()`... I would try this :)

Comment: Yeah, always struggling where to put it. Anyway - the problem still exists.

Comment: Having the same problem. I wonder if it's an emulator problem or also a real ICS device issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this may be an issue with the Android Emulator at present.

See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21237

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out. Also comment #5 provides an obvious work around: catch the exception and live with it for the moment. gnah <.< http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21237#c5

Answer (score 2):

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 300000, 500, locationListener);
```

In your code use this `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`  when you testing that make sure that the network you are using like WIFI is available or you are inserted sim card in your device and network is available on it.

You may also test using `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` but make sure before use that GPS is ON of device

Comment: Yes WiFi is available. (Otherwise I couldn't post this :P ).