# getLocationUpdates() giving illegal argument exception on 4.0 emulator

Tags: android, geolocation, android-webview

I saw on **code.google.com** that there is a bug in method getLocationUpdate() when we try the following:

**requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f, this);**

it throws :

```
09-06 22:46:16.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(351): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network
09-06 22:46:16.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(351):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1325)
09-06 22:46:16.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(351):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1275)
09-06 22:46:16.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(351):     at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:646)
09-06 22:46:16.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(351):     at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:582)
09-06 22:46:16.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(351):     at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:446)
```

Here is the link: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19857

I want to know is this fixed yet.My app is crashing everytime it tries to get the location update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please first implements     `implements LocationListener` if you have not written.

otherwise

Try this link [Get current Lat Lon](http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/geting-current-location-in-android-using-gps/) i have solve my problem with this link.
Try this one...
Best of luck

And also try with using `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` istead of `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`.

Comment: LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER works fine.the problem is with requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f, this);

Comment: Network Provider need Internet Connection in your mobile then it works fine..

Try with the code which are in the given link.

Comment: Rest is working fine...The only problem is witn network_provider.

Answer (score 0):

see this thread,this will do it for you... if you are working in the emulator...
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990129/illegalargumentexception-thrown-by-requestlocationupdate)