# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network

Tags: java, android, android-intent, geolocation

My android app sometimes throws this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2517)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4784)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:845)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:657)
at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:686)
at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:508)
```

In this line:

```
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mNetlocListener);
```

What have I done wrong?

I use the network enum provider.

Comment: which code? it fails in the registration to the locationProvider. all is default implementation

Comment: The code where you got this Crashed.

Comment: but i wrote this line already

Comment: possible duplicate of [IllegalArgumentException thrown by requestLocationUpdate()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990129/illegalargumentexception-thrown-by-requestlocationupdate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first check whether the LocationManagers NETWORK_PROVIDER is enabled

```
if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
       mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,mNetlocListener);
    }
```

Comment: it might help. but i cannot reproduce the exception with the old (!) code. what would you recommend?

Comment: If it help you a little atleast give +1. Anyany you can use LocationManager.getBestProvider() instead